# Wrong problem in Polynomials by Barbeau

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

On page 6 in Barbeau's Polynomials, the following problem is given:

[image]

I attempted to prove it by induction with the base case as $k = 1$. It is trivially true since $1+t = 1+t$ for all $t$. But if we take $k = 2$, the equation asserts that $1 + t + t^2 + t^3 = 1+ t+t^2$ which is not true for all $t$.

Am I correct that there is something wrong, or am I making some mistake in understanding the problem?

Comment: Yes, there's a typo.  Can you figure out what it should say?

Comment: The largest term in the sum is not right.

Comment: @saulspatz I believe the largest term on he right should be $t^{2^{k-1}+k}$

Comment: No, it should be $t^{2^k-1}$  Do you know about binary numbers?  That's the key to the proof.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh right, sorry. I was in a hurry and only checked up till $n=3$. I think that we get the last term by summing $k$ terms of the GP $1,2,4,...$ and get $2^k - 1$. How did you use binary numbers?

Comment: You don't really; I just meant it's the same logic that each positive integer has a unique binary expansion.  Kind of a hint -- if you have trouble, think about binary numbers.